# A PWM object already exists for this GPIO channel

Tags: led, python-3, pwm

I have a bit of a dilemma. I am currently using BCM GPIO 14, 15 and 18 to control an RGB status LED using PWM. I have configured my raspberry pi 3 to pull down pin 14 (red) on boot, to indicate the system is booting, but once I run my script the first time, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: A PWM object already exists for this GPIO channel
```

On error, the script shuts down and runs GPIO.cleanup(), turning off the LED. On the next try, it works fine, since the LED is off upon initialization.

The way I initialize the status LED is:

```
class Status:
    def __init__(self, red_pin, green_pin, blue_pin):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(red_pin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.setup(green_pin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.setup(blue_pin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)

        self.red_pin = GPIO.PWM(red_pin, 300)
        self.green_pin = GPIO.PWM(green_pin, 300)
        self.blue_pin = GPIO.PWM(blue_pin, 300)

        self.red_pin.start(100)
        self.green_pin.start(0)
        self.blue_pin.start(100)
    def set_led_color(self, r, g, b):
        red_cycle = 100 - (r * 100) / 255
        green_cycle = 100 - (g * 100) / 255
        blue_cycle = 100 - (b * 100) / 255

        self.red_pin.ChangeDutyCycle(red_cycle)
        self.green_pin.ChangeDutyCycle(green_cycle)
        self.blue_pin.ChangeDutyCycle(blue_cycle)
    def __del__(self):
        print("Status led is going offline")
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Please note that the reason I'm setting all pins to HIGH on init is that my LED is a common anode LED.

I can understand that since GPIO 14 is HIGH, the GPIO.PWM on that pin can have issues, but I do not know exactly how to reset that pin upon initialization.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using GPIO 14, 15, 18, not pins 14, 15, 18.  See https://pinout.xyz/ If the script runs first time without error are you sure it's not just a case of calling the RPi.GPIO cleanup() method before you exit?

Comment: There is no point posting code, and omitting vital parts.

Comment: You might find gpiozero easier:
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#pwmled
https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#rgbled

Comment: @joan sorry for not being clear. The first time it runs, it throws this error. After this error occurs, GPIO.cleanup() is called (on object destruction), and the LED turns off. After a second try, the issue no longer appears because the LED was off.

Comment: @Milliways what do you mean?

Comment: I think Milliways means that code snippets are not that useful.  If I had seen the full code I might not have mentioned the cleanup() method.

Comment: @joan i see, sorry for the confusion. Yes, indeed you are right, I am calling the GPIO cleanup method before I exit, that's why it works on second try, but what I do not know is how can I overwrite the red_pin so upon init, so that the error will go away?

Comment: We are having to guess, not the best use of our time.  It's better if you add the  complete script to your question.

Comment: @joan I edited my post